# Embedding visio diagram in word document adds padding to right and bottom (2019)

Tags: ms-word, embed, visio

I am using Word and Visio 2019. Created a new word document, and a new Visio document (8.5x11). I then created a swimlane in Visio and resized it to 6.5" and then CTRL+A, CTRL+C in Visio, and then CTRL+V in word, and word for some reason adds whitespace to the right and bottom of the diagram.

I can crop this whitespace away, but there is no way to tell word to crop to a specific size so I get some random sized diagram in my document. Is there a way to auto crop the added whitespace, or tell Word to import the diagram without adding the white space?

**Update:**
Fixed CTRL+P -> CTRL+V.
Also, it appears that this was a bug with Word/Visio as the problem disappeared after an update.

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce this, but in Visio  can you select your shape, then go to Developer Tab, Shape Designs, Operations, Update Alignement Box.   How to get the Dev. Tab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-the-developer-tab-on-the-ribbon?view=vs-2019

Comment: Also this question is probably better suited for SU instead of SO, I flagged it accordingly.

Comment: and I assume you used `Ctrl+V`, not `Ctrl+P`

Comment: Also, regarding the first comment, how does the selection look in visio, is the selection box the same as the "wrong" box in Word does it only encompass the actual shape.

Comment: The selection in visio is not the same as the wrong box. I have also been able to reproduce this on more than one machine with Word and Visio 2019 set up. I can even get this to happen with other objects like Excel.

Comment: I am going to close this. After my system was updated, I can no longer reproduce this issue. Both Visio and Excel work fine now, and there is no longer any strange whitespace. My guess is this was some sort of bug that was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with an update to Word.